# Why graphics::plot call on hexbin object throws an error?

Tags: r, plot

In short: I'm trying to run [this hexbin example](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/100-high-density-scatterplot-with-binning.html) which works fine unless I replace `plot` with `graphics::plot`. The latter throws following error:

```
> graphics::plot(bin, main="" , colramp=my_colors , legend=F )
Error in as.double(y) :
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

How to make this work?

Wider context why I need this work this way. I contribute to the [clojisr project](https://github.com/scicloj/clojisr) which brings R to Clojure using RServe. There is an option to require R packages and create corresponding Clojure functions. This works well (see [this](https://nextjournal.com/generateme/datavis-in-clojure-using-r) or [this](https://scicloj.github.io/clojisr/resources/public/clojisr/v1/titanic0-test/index.html)). The underlying calls to R are in the form of `{package::symbol}` for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `hexbin` is an S4 class and the package defines an S4 generic and a method for `plot`. (The source code is [here](https://github.com/edzer/hexbin/blob/981b2fbd95ce42ec0f35164337c610dcd6c08106/R/hexbin.s4.R#L319)). There is no S4 generic for `plot` in the `graphics` package namespace, only an S3 generic.

The solution is therefore very simple:

```
hexbin::plot(bin, main="" , colramp=my_colors , legend=F )
```

Here's a reprex to prove it:

```r
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Create data
x <- rnorm(mean=1.5, 5000)
y <- rnorm(mean=1.6, 5000)

# Make the plot
bin<-hexbin(x, y, xbins=40)
my_colors=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
hexbin::plot(bin, main="" , colramp=my_colors , legend=F )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You should mention that it's an S4 generic.

Comment: Thanks. That means that users of our library have to be aware of this and select proper function from given package (I suspect there will be more such case).

Comment: Another question raises: how then simple `plot` works and dispatches properly? `plot` and `graphics::plot` are considered the same by R.

Comment: @generateme It's because when you attach a package namespace by calling `library`, the namespace is added as a parent of the global environment. This means that R will include that namespace in a search for how to dispatch the method for the given object. You can see this is the case if you detach the hexbin package with `detach("package:hexbin", unload = TRUE)` and try to use `plot` rather than `hexbin::plot` - it will throw the same error that you had before, because native R doesn't know what to do with a `hexbin`

Comment: @AllanCameron Got it. Thanks a lot!